# Given two polar form equations, finding the length and angle by dividing them.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

[image: Question]

So I need to find the length and angle here, but I'm so confused as to what the w=formula is, what does that R mean and how do I divide these?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is just the norm of $w$ as $r$ is the norm of $z$. It's written like that for the sake of notation.

To compute $\dfrac{z}{w}=z\dfrac{1}{w}$ take into account that $\dfrac{1}{w}$ is the complex number that, when multiplied by $w$, gives you $1$. You also need to know that given two complex numbers in exponential form, say $r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $r_2e^{i\theta_2}$, the product of them gives us the complex number $r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$.

Knowing this it's easy to see that $\dfrac{1}{w}=\dfrac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}$, since in order to get $1$ when multiplying $w$ by it we need to get $r$ to transform into $1$ (the norm of $1$), which is done by $r\dfrac{1}{r}=1$, and we also need $\theta$ to transform into $0$ (the angle of $1$), which is done by $\theta+(-\theta)=0$.

The expression for $\dfrac{z}{w}$ (with $w\neq0$ of course) follows easily from this.